# Monitoring DB2 Queries at live

Tags: db2, monitoring

I would like to know if the DB2 data base has any kind of Monitoring tools.

For example. I use Navicat to manage Mysql Bases, and Navicat has a monitor tool that shows me which queries are running at that momment and i can close the processes. So... Does the Db2 Has any kind of monitoring tool?

Comment: That depends on your DB2 version and platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use db2top.

There is a nice blog about using db2top here - http://www.thekguy.com/db2top

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you mention that you use Navicat to manage MySQL databases.

Navicat interfaces with MySQL to give you reports on the state of your databases, but Navicat is not part of the MySQL database management subsystem, rather it relies on information that MySQL makes available to Navicat in order for it to generate its reports that give you your insight into how well they are performing.

There are monitoring products out there that do the same with DB2. i.e. interface with DB2 and give insight into what work is being processed and overall system health.

What monitoring tools there are available to you depend on where your DB2 subsystem runs, mainframe or Linux/Unix/Windows. Different platforms with different solutions, but common among them is that they report on the health of your DB2 subsystem and the elements contained within it.

So the basic answer to your question is, yes, there are monitoring and reporting tools and applications available to monitor a DB2 subsystem, the work it is doing, and the state of the objects within (databases, tables, indexes and the data within them).